# Linux daemon start up

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, daemon, redhat

*i wrote one service on linux(Redhat Server Edition 5.1) . which is started by shell scritpt, 
In case when i start my application i manually start my service , now i want to start my service at boot time,by means i put my service on init.d folder by my daemon not invoke at boot time,any have idea how to  start a daemon at boot time on linux?*

this my sample but is not working

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# myservice     This shell script takes care of starting and stopping
#               the <myservice>
#

# Source function library
. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions


# Do preliminary checks here, if any
#### START of preliminary checks #########


##### END of preliminary checks #######


# Handle manual control parameters like start, stop, status, restart, etc.

case "$1" in
  start)
    # Start daemons.

    echo -n $"Starting <myservice> daemon: "
    echo
    daemon <myservice>
    echo
    ;;

  stop)
    # Stop daemons.
    echo -n $"Shutting down <myservice>: "
    killproc <myservice>
    echo

    # Do clean-up works here like removing pid files from /var/run, etc.
    ;;
  status)
    status <myservice>

    ;;
  restart)
    $0 stop
    $0 start
    ;;

  *)
    echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|restart}"
    exit 1
esac

exit 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put 2 comments into your script:

```
# chkconfig: - 90 10
# description: description of your service
```

As root, run :

```
chkconfig --add my_service
```

Comment: what's going to happen added  two comment line to that script i cant get you,

Comment: These lines will tell chkconfig in which runlevel your script is supposed to run, and the start and stop priorities. See this : http://linux.die.net/man/8/chkconfig

Comment: if the service is already listed, you may need to run chkconfig --del my_service before you do the --add

Answer (score 3):

a basic unix daemon does the following:

```
fork
close all filedescriptors (stdout,stderr, etc)
chdir /
signal handeling (sighup, sigterm etc)
while
do stuff
sleep(xx)
done
```

(example in C: daemon.c)

Red Hat example on how to install startup scripts:

to start a deamon at system startup in redhat you need a init script.
it should be placed in /etc/init.d

example of init script :

Code:

```
# chkconfig: 3 99 1
# description: my daemon

case "$1" in
'start')
/usr/local/bin/mydaemon
;;

'stop')
pkill mydaemon
;;

'restart')
pkill -HUP mydaemon
;;

esac
```

the first line will tell chkconfig to start the daemon in run level 3 with priority 99 and kill it as priority 1 when server shutdowns.

to install the startup script use the following: chkconfig --add ./scriptabove
Now it will start when the server boots.

to start it right away use: service  start

If you want more details information visit [a link](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/442412-managing-linux-daemons-with-init-scripts)

Hope this helps somewhat!

Comment: but when i added like this i will get an error, check config doesn't support

Answer (score 0):

Different linux distributions include different service management facilities. You should have a look at [launchd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launchd), [OpenRC](http://www.gentoo.org/proj/en/base/openrc/) (present on Gentoo) and [SystemD](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/) (on Arch, for instance)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Ah I hadn’t seen it was specific to RedHat. I’ll leave my answer for future readers anyways.

Comment: Nitpick: It’s “systemd” (no capitalization), as pointed out on the page you linked to :). Also, systemd is shipped with Fedora, Arch, Mageia, Mandriva, openSUSE, Chakra, NixOS and Frugalware. It is available (but not the default init system) on Debian and Gentoo. launchd however seems to be used only on Mac OS X, see also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launchd

Answer (score 0):

chkconfig --add your_service_name